# Is it possible to customize grub using grub-customizer in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, grub2

I recently switched from Ubuntu to Fedora, and I installed `grub-customizer` and the entries doesn't contain Fedora.
[image: Grub Customizer]
I have triple boot - Fedora,Ubuntu and W10.

`os-prober` give the following output:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
/dev/nvme0n1p7:Ubuntu 21.04 (21.04):Ubuntu:linux
```

Few topics are opened on Fedora's forums but they keep circling to other topics.

Some resources I've tried looking at:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/grub-customizer-fedora-entry-not-visible/12526
https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/epqg4j/how_can_i_install_grub_customizer_on_fedora_31/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/gvumqx/no_options_of_fedora_in_grub_customizer_help_to/
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/

After some reading, I came to know that from Fedora 30 and above, there has been changes in [BLS](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/BootLoaderSpecByDefault)(no idea what that is).

So I want to know if it is possible use grub-customizer to customize grub?